# fontspec: Load an italic text font so that it has the same x-height as the "main" (roman) text font

Tags: fonts, fontsize, fontspec

Suppose that one likes the "upright" shape of the font `Sabon Next LT Pro`, but prefers the "italic" shape of the font `Garamond Premier Pro` over the italic shape of Sabon Next. (Both fonts are Garamond-style fonts, by the way.) Unfortunately, the x-heights of these fonts are quite different, creating some visual unpleasantness when they're typeset side by side.

I know of the option

```
Scale = MatchLowercase
```

when loading sans-serif and typewriter fonts via `\setsansfont` and `\setmonofont` statements; these options serve to scale the sans-serif and typewriter fonts to the x-height of the main text font in use. Unfortunately, there seems to be no (documented) way to set the x-height of an italics text font in the same easy way. Is this impression incorrect?

In short, how should I go about scaling my italics text font to equate its x-height to that of the main (Roman/upright) text font?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the main font first to set the x-height; then you can reset it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lucida Bright OT}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
  ItalicFeatures={Scale=MatchLowercase},
  ItalicFont={EB Garamond 12 Italic},
]{Lucida Bright OT}

\begin{document}
Abc\emph{def}

%% We check what the normal choice would be    
{\fontspec{Lucida Bright OT}Abc}{\fontspec{EB Garamond}\itshape def}

\end{document}
```

Apologies for the terrible font combination: I chose a font with a large x-height (Lucida Bright) for better comparison.

I learned the trick of setting twice the main font from Silex (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104000/4427)

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! The solution turns out to be much easier than I thought it'd be.