# Activate swash or alternate for Italic only

Tags: fonts, xetex

As per the Title: I would like to activate a swash or alternate only when I use italic.

I am aware than I can activate it globally during the `\setmainfont` section of the pre-amble but do not know how to set an effective 'rule' that whenever I put text in the `\emph` style, it also applies certain font styles.

I am using `font spec` and XeLaTeX.

Thanks

Pwdr

Comment: do you really mean `\emph` or any italic. `\emph` just chooses between `\textit` and `\textrm` depending on the slope of the current font, do you want alternate glyphs if italic is chosen by `\textit` explicitly, and what do you want to happen if `\emph` chooses `\textrm` as the current font is already italic?

Comment: any italic, really. I've been using `\emph` to activate as I've seen advised on here before.

Comment: well, as noted, `\emph` does not always choose an italic font, so it is bad markup if italic font is what you want.

Comment: Ok. I can modify that. Is `\textit` better than the `\itshape{}` command? How would I go about setting the rule for either of those?

Comment: `\textit` and `\itshape` select the same font so make no difference to `fontspec` It looks like you can specify features for just italic fonts using italicfeatures key, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115286/fontspec-load-an-italic-text-font-so-that-it-has-the-same-x-height-as-the-main

Comment: `ItalicFeatures={}`. Remarkably straightforward. Thanks!

Comment: It is `\textit{}` and `\itshape` i.e. the first, not the second, takes an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify features just for Italic using `fontspec`s `ItalicFeatures` key:

```
\setmainfont{...}[Ligatures=TeX,
  ItalicFeatures={...},
                 %^^^^
  ItalicFont={....},
]
```